# Errors when running php code to upload image to a given path

Tags: php, sql, image, variables, undefined

This is the php i've used for uploading an image (from W3schools):

```
<?php
            $target_dir = "images/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename("firstfood.jpg");
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            if(isset($_POST "submit")) {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES "firstfood.jpg");
                if($check !== false) {
                    echo "File is an image - " . $check "mime" . ".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES "firstfood.jpg", $target_file)) {
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES "firstfood.jpg"). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

When I add it to the mainphp file (see in the middle of below code), with the path substitutions,

```
<?php // sqltest.php
  require_once 'login.php';
  $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

  if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
  {
    $isbn   = get_post($conn, 'isbn');
    $query  = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }

  if (isset($_POST['author'])   &&
      isset($_POST['title'])    &&
      isset($_POST['category']) &&
      isset($_POST['year'])     &&
      isset($_POST['isbn']) &&
      isset($_POST['sleeve'])) 

  {
    $author   = get_post($conn, 'author');
    $title    = get_post($conn, 'title');
    $category = get_post($conn, 'category');
    $year     = get_post($conn, 'year');
    $isbn     = get_post($conn, 'isbn');
    $sleeve   = get_post($conn, 'sleeve');          

    $query    = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
      "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn', '$sleeve')";
    $result   = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
      $conn->error . "<br><br>";
  }

  echo <<<_END

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
    Author <input type="text" name="author">
     Title <input type="text" name="title">
  Category <input type="text" name="category">
      Year <input type="text" name="year">
      ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn">
      Sleeve <input type="file" name="sleeve">
         <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">


            <?php
            $target_dir = "images/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename("firstfood.jpg");
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            if(isset($_POST "submit")) {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES "firstfood.jpg");
                if($check !== false) {
                    echo "File is an image - " . $check "mime" . ".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES "firstfood.jpg", $target_file)) {
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES "firstfood.jpg"). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
            ?>


           <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
  </pre></form>
_END;

  $query  = "SELECT * FROM classics";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

  $rows = $result->num_rows;

  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
  {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo <<<_END
  <pre>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sqltest.php" method="post"> 
    Author <input type="text" name="author" value=$row[0]>
     Title <input type="text" name="title" value=$row[1]>
  Category <input type="text" name="category" value=$row[2]>
      Year <input type="text" name="year" value=$row[3]>
      ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn" value=$row[4]> 

  </pre>

  <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="$row[4]">
    <input type="submit" value="EDIT RECORD"></form>
  <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"></form>

_END;
  }

  $result->close();
  $conn->close();

  function get_post($conn, $var)
  {
    return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  }
?>
```

It throws out a whole bunch of errors (all of which relate to the section of code i pasted first - for uploading an image). Here are a few:

- Notice: Undefined variable: target_dir
- Notice: Undefined variable:imageFileType
- Notice: Undefined variable: target_file

Would really appreciate guidance on this, as I'm just starting out and can get around this. thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you won't get interpreted that <?php ?> inserted between <<<_END _END;

```
echo <<<_END
<form>
<?php $string = ''; echo $string ?>
</form>
_END;
```

this gonna be treated as

```
echo "<form><?php $string = ''; echo $string ?></form>";
```

so you see errors "undefined variable" because it's same as

```
echo "<form><?php ". $string ."= ''; echo ". $string ." ?></form>";
```

check the source code of generated page, you will get sure.

Try this instead, it's not ideal, but will work in every case ;)

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<form>
<?php $string = ''; echo $string ?>
</form>
<?= ob_get_clean() ?>
```

---

and btw you have 2x </form> there

```
<input type="submit" value="EDIT RECORD"></form>
<input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"></form>
```

Comment: @Relocc thanks for pointing out the issue; i got rid of the echo and instead wrapped the remaining parts in  <?php  ?>. thanks a million.

Comment: @AgniScribe glad to help.